# POST данные приходят как false

Tags: post, ajax, codeigniter

Отправляю данные по ajax вот так:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/admin/page/ajax',
data: {action: "up", id : 1},
type: 'JSON',
});
```

Обрабатываю в контроллере Codeingiter

```
public function ajax() {
    if( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() )
        show_404();

    $return = new stdClass;
    $return->action = $this->input->post(NULL, false);

    switch ($this->input->post("action", true)) {
        case 'save_page':
            $return->method = $this->page->save();
            redirect("/admin/page");
            break;

        case 'publish':
            $return->method = $this->page->publish();
            break;

        case 'unpublish':
            $return->method = $this->page->unpublish();
            break;

        case 'remove':
            $return->method = $this->page->remove();
            break;

        default:
           $return->method = false;
            break;
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Ответ от сервера всегда приходит вот такой:

```
{action: false, method: false}
```

Вопрос:
Почему у меня $this->input->post() всегда false?
Как это победить? Возможно хитрый параметр в config?
Какие хитрости CI я упустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/admin/page/ajax',
data: {action: "up", id : 1},
type: 'JSON',
});
```

За решением далеко ходить не нужно: `type:JSON`

Будьте чуть внимательней. Для указания формата возвращаемого ответа вы должны добавить опцию на `dataType`.

Comment: Ой))) Действительно глупо... Спасибо, пойду высплюсь :)

Answer (score 0):

так все правильно
вы передаете параметр action = "up"
такой параметр у вас не обрабатывается и срабатывает следующий ваш код

```
 default:
           $return->method = false;
            break;
```

и соответсвенно вызвращается значение false

Comment: Да, все верно... Ошибся когда сюда код писал.
Но суть не в этом, даже если я посылаю правильный параметр "action" картина в целом такая-же.

Если изменить конструкцию в $.ajax на $.post - то все становится нормально. Данные приходят.

С чем это может быть связано?

PS: Извините, плюсик клацнуть пока не могу :(